# Replace multiple spaces by single space in C

Tags: c, replace, whitespace

I want to repace multiple spaces in a string by single space, however my following code doesn't work. What's the logical mistake?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
char input[100];
int i,j,n,z=0;
scanf("%d",&n);
z=n;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
scanf("%c",&input[i]);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(input[i]==' ' && (input[i+1]==' ' || input[i-1]==' '))
    {
        --z;
        for(j=i;j<n;j++)
        input[j]=input[j+1];
    }
}
for(i=0;i<z;i++)
    printf("%c",input[i]);
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `scanf` makes some issue. Instead use `gets` OR `scanf("%s",input)`.

Comment: wrong `if(input[i]==' ' && (input[i+1]==' ' || input[i-1]==' '))`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , whats wrong?

Comment: see sample code of my answer

Comment: @Navnath: please do not suggest `gets()`. It is impossible to easy safely and no longer (since 2011) in the C Standard. Suggest `fgets()` which is perfectly reasonable for reading interactive user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scanf` is giving you some problem: it reads the `\n`  you give after inputting the length `n`. So, you will miss the last character since `for` loop exits. The already given answers are good enough. But if you want to follow your own logic, try this:

```
void main()
{
    char input[100];
    int i = 0,j,n = 0;
    while ((input[n] = getchar()) != '\n') {
        n++;
    }
    input[n] = '\0';
    while (i < n)
    {
        if(input[i]==' ' && (input[i+1]==' ' || input[i-1]==' '))
        {
            for(j=i;j<n;j++)
            input[j]=input[j+1];
            n--;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",input);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: looks to me that this solution is O(n^2). there is an O(n) solution.

Answer (score 7):

I would do something like this:

```
void replace_multi_space_with_single_space(char *str)
{
    char *dest = str;  /* Destination to copy to */

    /* While we're not at the end of the string, loop... */
    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        /* Loop while the current character is a space, AND the next
         * character is a space
         */
        while (*str == ' ' && *(str + 1) == ' ')
            str++;  /* Just skip to next character */

       /* Copy from the "source" string to the "destination" string,
        * while advancing to the next character in both
        */
       *dest++ = *str++;
    }

    /* Make sure the string is properly terminated */    
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

Of course, the above function requires you to properly terminate the string, which you currently do not.

What the function above does, is basically copy the string over itself. The exception is when there is a space, when multiple spaces are simply discarded.

Since the function modifies the source string, it can not be used on string literals.

Answer (score 2):

`if(input[i]==' ' && (input[i+1]==' ' || input[i-1]==' '))`

case " 1 3" : when i == 0 accses input[i-1] Out-of-Bounds

`scanf("%d",&n);`

remain newline, (input[0] <-- '\n')

fix to

`scanf("%d%*c",&n);`

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* uniq_spc(char* str){
    char *from, *to;
    int spc=0;
    to=from=str;
    while(1){
        if(spc && *from == ' ' && to[-1] == ' ')
            ++from;
        else {
            spc = (*from==' ')? 1 : 0;
            *to++ = *from++;
            if(!to[-1])break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main(){
    char input[]= "  abc   de  f  ";

    printf("\"%s\"\n", uniq_spc(input));//output:" abc de f "
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: + your answer(I saw other also) are very good, but bit explanation will help OP/and others more :)

Comment: `to[-1]` introduced the `spc` flag to avoid sequence range.

Answer (score 1):

Why make it more complicated than it needs to be? You can use `strtok` to check for single whitespaces and just ignore those. Then you can use `strcat` to concatenate the string into a full sentence and then you're done.

This is how I did it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char *pch;
    char sentence[1000];
    char without[1000];

    printf("Sentence: ");
    fgets(sentence,1000, stdin);
    strtok(sentence, "\n"); // remove any newlines
    pch = strtok(sentence, " ");
    while(pch != NULL) {
      strcat(without, pch);
      strcat(without, " \0");
      pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    without[strlen(without)-1] = '\0'; // remove extra whitespace at the end
    printf("|%s|\n",without);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void remove_blanks(char* s);

int main()
{
    char const s[] = {'1',' ',' ','2',' ',' ','3'};
    remove_blanks(s);
    printf("%s",s);
    return 0;
}

void remove_blanks(char* s){
    int i=0, delta=0, cnt=0;

    for (i=0;s[i];++i){
        if (s[i]==' ') cnt++;
        if (cnt>1){
            delta+=1;
            cnt=0;
        }
        s[i-delta]=s[i];
        if(delta>0) s[i]='\0';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant try this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main() {
  int c, spaces, state;

  spaces = 0;
  state = OUT;  
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

      if ( c == ' ') {
           ++spaces;
           state = OUT;
       }
      else if (state == OUT) {
          state = IN;
          spaces = 0;
      }
      if (c == ' ' && spaces > 1 && state == OUT)
          c = 0;            
      putchar(c);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the following for loop. the limit of your for loop should be `z` and not `n`

```
for(j=i;j<n;j++)
input[j]=input[j+1];
```

by

```
for(j=i;j<z;j++)
input[j]=input[j+1];
```

**BTW**: the fist charachter get by your `scanf()` (which read charachters) is newline (`\n`). this newline come from the first `scanf()` of decimal(`%d`)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
    {
        char input[1000];
        int i=0;
        gets(input); 
        for(i=0;input[i]!='\0';i++)
        {
            if(input[i]!=' ' || input[i+1]!=' ')
                printf("%c",input[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way, using two methods from string.h library:

```
void strRemoveBlanks(char* _s){
    char* ptr = NULL;
    while ((ptr = strstr(_s, "  ")) != NULL)
        memmove(ptr, ptr + 1, strlen(ptr));
};
```