# Using Memmove to copy a string into itself produces wrong output

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm given a string as such:

```
"Hello     World"
```

With 5 Spaces characters inbetween the two words. I want to remove all but one of the spaces between the two words . However, my code seems to only work when there is 3 spaces or less. I'm using `memmove` to try and accomplish this.

Here is what I've tried:

```
int main(void) {
    char * word = malloc(sizeof(char)*16);

    strcpy(word,"Hello     World");
    checkWords(word);

    return 0;
}

void checkWords(char * word) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
        if(word[i] == ' ' ) 
            memmove(&word[i],&word[i+1],strlen(word)+1);
    }

    printf("The string without spaces is %s\n",word);
}
```

The output here is `"Hello  World"`
Not `"Hello World"`

If It try input such as:

```
"Hello  World" gets me "Hello World" -->correct

 "Hello   World" gets me "Hello World" -->correct
```

anything greater than 3 spaces, gets me incorrect output. (I want to have one space between the two words.

Comment: Warning, with `memmove`, you have to deals with `\0` character.

Comment: I've updated my code to use memmove, the issue still persists. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this `if(word[i] == ' ' && word[i+1] == ' ') {
           memmove(&word[i],&word[i+1],strlen(word)+1);
                i--;
        }`

Comment: @rerere Not the problem here, but `strlen(word)+1)` is wrong, because you are reading past the allocated memory which is undefined behaviour (even if most of the time you'll probably get away with it). It should be `strlen(&word[i+1])+1)`

Comment: [Replace multiple spaces by single space in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790227/replace-multiple-spaces-by-single-space-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the "right" side of the string potentially multiple times is inefficient.  Use of `strcpy()` or `memcpy()` is not an efficient approach.

Repeatedly calling `strlen()` is also inefficient.

Suggest using two indexes and walk them through the string.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void RemoveExtraSpaces(char * word) {
  if (word[0]) {
    size_t src = 1;
    size_t dest = 1;
    do {
      if (word[src] != ' ' || word[src - 1] != ' ') {
        word[dest] = word[src];
        dest++;
      }
    } while (word[src++]);
  }
  printf("The string without spaces is `%s`\n", word);
}
```

Unclear what should happen with multiple spaces before the first word or after the last word.  This code shrinks those to 1 space.

---

After accept variation - slight simplification.  Inspired by [@Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16790505/2410359) good answer.

```
void RemoveExtraSpaces2(char * word) {
  size_t src = 0;
  size_t dest = 0;
  do {
    if (word[src] == ' ' && word[src + 1] == ' ') {
      src++;
    }
    word[dest] = word[src];
    dest++;
  } while (word[src++]);

  printf("The string without spaces is `%s`\n", word);
}
```

---

As this is too close to being a duplicate of [Replace multiple spaces by single space in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16790227/2410359), (BTW: which did not accept the best answer IMO), I am making this community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

There are four problems. One is undefined behaviour: Take a 1,000,000 byte string where just the last character is a space. You will be moving about one megabyte *after the end of the string* one byte forward. That's quite fatal.

One is just a bug: You examine every character position in the string only once. If you have two consecutive spaces, you move the second space into the position of the first one and leave it there.

And one is a performance issue: If you fix the first two problems, and then you take a 1,000,000 byte string consisting of spaces only, you will do one million memmoves each moving between 0 and 1 megabyte. That's 500 gigabyte moved. That takes time.

And another performance issue is calling strlen in a loop. If your string is one million bytes, you do one million calls to strlen, and each call will go through the whole string until the end, scanning the whole megabyte string for the trailing zero byte.

PS. I misinterpreted what you are trying to achieve: Your code will delete any single space, and delete one out of any pairs of spaces. So it leaves one space for every two spaces you had. So it won't work if there is one space. It works by coincidence for two or three spaces. And if you have lots of spaces, it will keep about half of them.

Comment: Nice explanation - except I do not think first paragraph applies.  `while (word[i+1] == ' '...` is never true in your 1,000,000 byte case.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
for(i=0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
    if(word[i] == ' ' ) 
    {
        while (word[i+1] == ' ' && word[i+1] != '\0')
            memmove(&word[i],&word[i+1], strlen(word)-i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It was neccessary a "while" to reach all the spaces

Comment: May work , but is  inefficient.  `O(n*n)`.  Yet OP is not looking for efficiency.

Comment: Inefficient, the better method would be find the first "non space" position and do only __one__ `memmove`.

Comment: ...and calling `strlen` in the end condition of the `for` is also inefficient. Why? I leave the explanation as an exercice to the reader.

Comment: On SO we prefer answers that address and explain the original issue, not "just throw out your code and use mine" pseudo-solutions.

Comment: @chux I don't want to find the best way to do it, but only help to rerere with his/her code

Comment: Agree we do not need to provide the "best" answer.  Yet OP's approach retains significant weaknesses and that is worth noting, even once it is functionally fixed as answered here.